# optimisation to avoid repeating myself in program

Tags: javascript

I wrote this really simple Pizza order program below but i feel like i'm repeating myself in parts. Any optimisation tips?

Code:

```js
var orderCount = 0;

function takeOrder(crustType, topping) {
  console.log('Order:' + crustType + ' ' + 'pizza' + ' ' + topping);
  orderCount = orderCount + 1;
}

function getSubTotal(itemCount) {
  return itemCount * 7.5;
}

function calculateVat(VAT) {
  return VAT / 10 * 2;
}

// List the orders
takeOrder('Thin Crust Pizza', 'with bacon');
takeOrder('Fat Crust Pizza', 'with pepporoni');
takeOrder('Medium Crust Pizza', 'with Vegi');
takeOrder('Medium Crust Pizza', 'with steak');
takeOrder('Medium Crust Pizza', 'with Sausage');
// List the Total Minus VAT
console.log(getSubTotal(orderCount));

//Stores the cost with and With out VAT
var totalNoVAT = getSubTotal(orderCount);
var totalYesVAT = getSubTotal(orderCount) + calculateVat(totalNoVAT);

//Log the cost of the VAT and Total Order Cost with VAT
console.log('The VAT on that order would be' + ' ' + calculateVat(totalNoVAT));
console.log('This give you a grand total of' + ' ' + totalYesVAT);
```

Comment: Using functions like that doesn't actually feel very repetitive - you're doing fine! You might want to move the `'with '` from the `topping` strings into the `takeOrder` function though. Instead of calling the function repeatedly, you might want to use an array of orders and iterate that.

Comment: @vlaz by repetition, I guess OP means he has to call a function numerous times. He can remove that if he accepts params as array of objects

Comment: Hi Rajesh , thanks for the reply yeah more just opinions / advice , apologies will make sure i put is up there next time

Answer (score 4):

That's a neat little program you've got there.

Why don't you consider learning JavaScript Constructors through a Pizza Constructor?

```
function order(size, topping, price, customer, address) {
    this.Pizza = {
        Size: size;
        Toppings: toppings;
    },
    this.Price = price;
    this.Customer = customer;
    this.DeliveryAddress = address;
}

var order_one = new order ('12"', 'Pepperoni', 12.99, 'Josh', '1, Typical Street, Typicaltown');
```

Answer (score -1):

since your orderCount is global, you don't need to pass it in function getSubTotal. Also, save the getSubTotal() value in a variable. No need to call it again and again.